# window.matchMedia triggers too often (false positives)

Tags: javascript, media-queries

I’m setting up multiple media queries like:

```
for (var layoutId in layoutList) {
    console.log('Set up MediaQuery [%s]:', layoutId, getCssMediaQueryDefinition(layoutId));
    var mql = window.matchMedia(getCssMediaQueryDefinition(layoutId));
    mql.removeListener(onMatchMediaChange);
    mql.addListener(onMatchMediaChange);
}

var onMatchMediaChange = function (event) {
    console.log('onMatchMediaChange [%s]:', _.get(getLayoutForCssMediaQuery(event.media), 'id'), window.innerWidth, event.media);
};
```

When I start the app, the console looks like:

```
Set up MediaQuery [phone]: (max-width: 512px)
Set up MediaQuery [tablet]: (max-width: 1002px) and (min-width: 512px)
```

...which looks correct.

However, when I resize the window, this happens (console statements):

```
onMatchMediaChange [tablet]: 859 (max-width: 1002px) and (min-width: 512px)
onMatchMediaChange [phone]: 436 (max-width: 512px)
onMatchMediaChange [tablet]: 436 (max-width: 1002px) and (min-width: 512px)
```

The first two logs are correct, but the third is not: for some reason the media query for "tablet" falsely triggers immediately after "phone".

Any pointers what could be wrong?